# Error while using JSP with App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

This is my JSP file. The name of the file is NewFile.jsp.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello this is JSP Page
</body>
</html>
```

This is the servlet.

```
    package pack.exp;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JspTestingServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
     private static String Test_JSP = "/NewFile.jsp";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");

        String forward="";
        forward= Test_JSP;

        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher(forward);


        try 
        {
            view.forward(req, resp);
        }

        catch (ServletException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JspTesting</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pack.exp.JspTestingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JspTesting</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsptesting</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After deploying the application, I am getting HTTP 404 page not found error
I am new to jsp please somebody Help me.

Comment: Tell how the URL you are using to access the JSP and the web.xml entry of the servlet mapping.

Comment: u have forward it to NewFile.jsp,but u r having MyFile.jsp

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake, i have updated it.

Comment: Santosh i have upated the web.xml file.

Comment: @user2558087 do u have index.html if then what it has and when u r getting 404 error

Comment: @user2779544 yes i have it. It has something lyk this  <body>
    <h1>Hello App Engine!</h1>
 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Available Servlets:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="jspappengine">JspAppEngine</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

Comment: @user2779544 my app is deployed successfully, when the browser opens and i click on my available servlet  it give the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is in your web.xml as you have shown.

Your servlet class definition in web.xml is

```
<servlet-class>pack.exp.JspAppEngineServlet</servlet-class>
```

And your Servlet java file name is : `Jsp_App_EngineServlet`. There is a mismatch and hence it is not found.

So, change the Java file name to : `JspAppEngineServlet` and it should be fine.

Comment: Everything looks good to me. I have set your files up locally and the page comes up fine when you click on the Available Servlets. Does the app work locally? Can you upload the error page when you click on the Available Servlet ?

Comment: This is the new project, with the same code..
I deployed it on the app engine
You can check the error by clicking on this link
http://1.shanxdemo.appspot.com/

Comment: Your JSPTesting link in the above deployed app is refering to /jsptesting. This is not defined in your web.xml. In your web.xml, you have put /jspappengine. So correct that and it will be fine.

Comment: actualy i created a new project with the name "Jsp Testing"
so in my web.xml /jsptesting is written which is fine. i will upadate the ques now.

Comment: Well, I cannot help out if you are keeping inconsistent code over here and something else on the server. I dont see anything particularly wrong except for typos, missing declarations, etc. Another point is that you have JSPs in your project. Did you use a proper JDK, make sure that you did not get the errors while uploading to GAE and all that. Finally, does your project work locally?

Comment: Sorry for  the  inconsistency. I am using eclipse with proper plugin.
I am not getting any error while uploading to GAE.
I dont know how to run google web application on tomcat server. That's why i am unable to check it localy.

Comment: GAE Eclipse plugin comes with an inbuilt server. All you need to do to run locally is Right-click on your project, Run As - Web Application. It should ideally start up on port 8888. Then visit http://localhost:8888

Comment: i'm getting this error when running locally
Error 404 /NewFile.jsp

Hello, world